# Kubernetes mix config map and host path

Tags: kubernetes

Here is my deployment file and I am applying it with command `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

```sh
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
        name: scan-deployment
        labels:
            app: scan
    spec:
       replicas: 1
       selector:
           matchLabels:
               app: scan
       template:
           metadata:
               labels:
                   app: scan
           spec:
               volumes:
               - name: shared-files
                 configMap:
                    name: shared-files
               containers:
               - name: scan-svc
                 image: scan:latest
                 imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
                 volumeMounts:
                 - name: shared-files
                   mountPath: /shared
```

Here I have my file `test.txt` file which is located in `./shared/test.txt` that I have configured using configMap.

Now the thing is that I have subFolder in my local disk `./shared/xml`, `./shared/report` and I want to map `/shared` with container  but not able to do it. I don't want to map config files from these subfolder. Deployed code creates report in xml and pdf format and saves it in respective folder and I want to map that to local disk.

Answer (score 1):

[Configmaps don't support recursive directories.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62421) When you create Configmap from `./shared` directory, only the regular files in the directory are included. Sub directories are ignored.

You should create a regular volume from `./shared` directory then mount it to the container.

Comment: Can you please share how can I do it. I think I tried it but it is expecting unique value.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice, if you would tell us why you are not able to do it, but I assume it overwrites your content under `/shared`, which is an expected behavior.

When you map your `/shared`; on the host with `/shared` in the container, it is going to be mapped correctly, but once `configMap` gets created, it is going to overwrite the content of the path, by whatever is in the `configMap`.

Comment: I am actually new to kubernetes. But want to mount whole volume and config file in the same "'shared" directory

Comment: you can't do that. Once you mount the `configMap` it is going to wipe everything there, and make the directory read-only. You could map your host path to container, say `/shared:/shared`, and have another directory inside `/shared` in the host, (`/shared/something`), and map the `configMap` to `/shared/something`.